# Bind Ctr Down to cd command in Bash

Tags: bash, unix, input, key-bindings, cd

Recently I've been playing with inputrc a little and I thought it would be nice to bind the Ctrl-Up arrow (`^[[1;5A` on my machine) to the command `cd ..`

So I modified inputrc to include `"\e[1;5A": "cd ..\n"`

Now I want Ctrl-Down arrow to do the following:

- If there is only 1 directory in the current directory: cd into it.
  I can check if there is only 1 directory by doing:

  ```
  if [ $(ls -a --ignore . --ignore .. | wc -l) -eq 1 ]
  ```
- If there are multiple directories: do a "TAB TAB"
- If there is a single line of directories go to the bottom of the hierarchy

for example in the file structure

```
a

|-------b--------d

|

|-------c--------e--------f----------i--------j-------k

                |-----g

                |-----h
```

assuming `a` through `j` are directories and `a` is the parent of `b/c`, `c is the parent of`e`, etc...

Assuming I start from `a`,

- pressing ctrl-down will double TAB and show `b` and `c`
- typing in `cd a/c` and pressing ctr-down again will make my command `cd a/c/e` (just like how tab complete works)
- pressing ctrl-down again will show `f`, `g`, `h`
- typing in `f` so my command is now `cd a/c/e/f` and pressing ctrl-down
  will now make my command `cd a/c/e/f/i/j/k`

I know I will have to make a script and bind the script to ctrl-down arrow.  My question is how would I get something to append to the current command I'm typing, and check a lower directory based on what I have typed in without me needing to execute the command?